# struggling with inapp email in ios

Tags: ios

i am a newbie to iOS and am trying to add inapt email in my app. I have a screen in which pushing the email icon should open the inapp email. I have the code for the inapp email. However, the button is already an outlet on the controller. So, I don't know how to link the same button to a different class/file which has the code for the inapp email. I was thinking of setting up a delegate but don't know how to initialize the delegate in the mail class. Have been struggling for a few days...please help!

Sumit

Comment: Have you had a look at the [MFMailComposeViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)?  Because most of the mail-side work is done for you.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have the code for the mail side but am struggling with integrating it in my app. Cannnot figure out how to call the mail code. The mail code should be triggered if the value of a variable is set to zero. Not sure how to call the MFMail...should i use protocol? if yes, then don't know how to set the delegate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try MFMailComposeViewController.... here is some sample code:
Make sure you import the MEssageUI framework and import the MFMailComposeViewController/MessageUI in .h and also conform to its delegate

```
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];


        [mailView setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [mailView setSubject:@"Interesting Apple News Article!"];
        NSString *mailString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Test!"]; 
        [mailView setMessageBody:mailString isHTML:NO];
        [mailView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
        [mailString release];
        [mailView release];
    } else 
        [mailView release];

    }

   -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mailing Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} else {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


  }
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I have the code for the mail side but am struggling with integrating it in my app. Cannnot figure out how to call the mail code. The mail code should be triggered if the value of a variable is set to zero. Not sure how to call the MFMail...should i use protocol? if yes, then don't know how to set the delegate...

Comment: Not sure I understand u? So u mean like this:

Comment: hi Rohan...you are right in that i need mail to be triggered, if (value==0). So are you suggesting that if I copy your code in that if condition, it will work? Once again, thank you for your advise

Comment: To tick an answer just click the tick image to make it green!